# uwsgi + Django with nginx: High Availability Setup

Tags: nginx, python, high-availability, uwsgi, pacemaker

Moved from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304968/uwsgi-django-with-nginx-high-availability-setup to here.

**I was setting up High Availability on RHEL 6.5 . My Stack is**

```
1. uwsgi  
2. nginx  
3. django 
4. Pacemaker
```

Now I understand that nginx can be setup easily via monitoring the nginx_status

```
    location /nginx_status {
        # Turn on nginx stats
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        # Security: Only allow access from 192.168.1.100 IP #
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        # Send rest of the world to /dev/null #
        deny all;
    }
```

This would ensure the heartbeat monitoring for nginx.

But, my question is how to ensure that `uwsgi` would be in running state so that is when second nginx machine comes up it recognises the `uwsgi` process and be bind to it. Or if the `uwsgi` goes down, how to ensure to bring it up and rebind to `nginx`

## The setup goes as follows

assuming cluster machines :

```
1. x.x.x.x (main machine)
2. y.y.y.y (slave machine)
```

## Shared storage in

```
1. /apps (SAN)
```

/apps available in both the machines as shared storage

## The application running django + uwsgi in

```
1. virtualenv : /apps/venv
2. applicaiton in : /apps
3. uwsgi configuration in : /apps/config.d
4. running application : /apps/project
```

## uwsgi configuration

```
[uwsgi]

# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /apps/project

# Django's wsgi file
module          = project.wsgi

# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /apps/venv

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true

# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 4

# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/project.sock

# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 666

# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true

#daemonize
daemonize       = true

#logging
logger          = file:/tmp/uwsgi.log
```

I am not getting any idea about how `uwsgi` would be running in HA setup ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't run uwsgi in an HA setup. Just make nginx talk to a local uwsgi and run nginx in an HA setup with pacemaker or a loadbalander.

Comment: I am bit confused here, the `/apps` is shared between the `node1` and `node 2` (`node 1` as master and `node2` as slave). Now say node1 goes down, the node2 would come up with its own nginx, the nginx would read the socket from `/tmp/project.sock`. Great!! But the uwsgi would not be running by itself on `node2` so there would be no socket at `/tmp/project.sock`

So what should be a proper way

Comment: I wouldn't share /apps either but have a real deployment process :)

Comment: Ok, so you mean, /apps/project would be installed in both the nodes, and if one goes down ,  the other would come-up, and nginx would read from local socket. So at time of upgrade, i would have to upgrade code at both the nodes

Comment: Should I use XINETD for managing the `uwsgi` ? if node goes down, the xinetd would comeup on second node and would start the uwsgi ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: Actually I dont have a choice in the matter, the `/apps` is on SAN and `node1` and `node2` share the `/apps`
The server is RHEL6.5, and `python2.7` along with all the modules is stored in `/apps` only

Comment: Sure you have a choice, you can create a proper deployment procedure :)

Comment: Thanks !! I would be sharing this info with my boss as well. Lets see.